# How to merge two queries having different output into one query while sequence should remain same

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In different SQL queries when I merge into one while follow the same sequence.  Query are as follows-

```
select c1, c2, ....., 
convert(varchar, t2.col1) AS col from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.col2=t2.col1 AS col1,  
....., c15 from table;
```

Here in above previous lots of columns before `JOIN` are there to fetch the data and mentioned as `c1`, `c2`, .... `c15` are the column to fetching the values also lots of column are there after `JOIN`. But I want all these things into one SQL query. I stuck only on one JOINING two different tables as one column.

Comment: I think the magic word you are looking for is UNION but your question isn't entirely clear, so I might be wrong. If you can provide a bit more context we might be able to help more.

Comment: It can be `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, and it can be another way depends on what your data is and outputs you want, you did not provide enough information to answer your question. So the acctual answer to this is **It depends**, which mean you post a **Too broad** question.

Comment: @Sami Before JOINING also some columns are there to fetch the data and also after JOINING also some columns are there to fetch but we have to follow the sequence in the SQL query. While in the SQL query I join another table.

Comment: Your question is still not clear... which sequence are you referring to?

Comment: @Raska some columns want to fetch as well as records from this JOINING condition also in one single query. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select all the columns as usual and at that time of `JOINING` write query like this-

```
select c1, c2, .....
convert(varchar, t2.col1) AS col,
...., c15 from table1 
inner join on table2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

The output you want merge into one.